# Byte-compile file only when library is found

Tags: emacs, compilation, bytecode

How can I advise the byte compiler not to compile an emacs-lisp source file when a library is not found? Note that the un-compilable file resides in the same directory as other files that should be compiled.

I have seen people wrap the entire file in a conditional clause, but that looks disgusting. It is also conceivable to autoload/declare every function, but in this case the entire file is rife with external calls. Is there an alternative?

Comment: Just `require` the file?  If the dependency isn't found, it will fail to compile.

Comment: that gives an error, which is not what I want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there's a good answer/solution to this problem, no.

What you can do is:

- either mark the file so it's *never* compiled (even when the library is available) with `no-byte-compile: t` somewhere in the file-local variables.
- or add all the needed `declare-function`s and `defvar`s to silence the byte-compiler warnings.  Note that this option will only work for *functions* and *variables* but not for macros: if you use macros from that library you'll need extra care to prevent those macro calls from being compiled when the library is not loaded (see for example `TeX--if-macro-fboundp` in AUCTex's `tex.el`).

Comment: yea I was aware or the `no-byte-compile`, it is too bad there isn't a `no-byte-compile-if`